# passing optional parameter to autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to use Autofac and register the below class which receives one of the parameter as optional parameter (or rather null).
My classes are:

```
class BaseSpanRecord : ISpanRecord
{
    public BaseSpanRecord(RecordType recordType, List<SpanRecordAttribute> properties)
    {
        RecordType = recordType;
        Properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Here *RecordType* is an enum and *SpanRecordAttribute* is a class with only properties for which i don't want to create any interface.

In the constructor *RecordType* and *Properties* are the two public properties of the interface *ISpanRecord*
This class can be instantiated in the following ways in different places in the program:

```
ISpanRecord spanFileRecord = new BaseSpanRecord(recordType, null);
```

or

```
ISpanRecord spanFileRecord = new BaseSpanRecord(recordType, recordAttributeList);
```

How should i try to register this in the Autofac container so that it can handle the above two cases?
Or should i change something in the way *BaseSpanRecord* class has been written to make its registration easier?

Comment: I tried using the following:
`builder.RegisterType<BaseSpanRecord>().UsingConstructor(typeof(RecordType),
                                                                    typeof(List<SpanRecordAttribute>)).As<ISpanRecord>().InstancePerDependency();`
But then it does not work for the first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `TypeParameter` to resolve the instance as long as you provide the type information `null` should be fine. You should not need to use the `UsingConstructor` method on your registration.

Creating TypedParameter instances directly:

```
var recordTypeParam = new TypedParameter(typeof(RecordType), RecordType.Something);
var propertiesParam = new TypedParameter(typeof(List<SpanRecordAttribute>), null);
var record = container.Resolve<ISpanRecord>(recordTypeParam, propertiesParam);
```

Using the `TypedParameter.From` helper method:

```
var record = container.Resolve<ISpanRecord>(TypedParameter.From(RecordType.Something), TypedParameter.From((List<SpanRecordAttribute>)null));
```

Notice that the `null` was cast to `List<SpanRecordAttribute>` to allow for type inference with the helper method.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. It solved my problem. But now couple of questions follow. When should i use `UsingConstructor()` or `WithParameter()` or `builder.Register(c=> new ClassA(c.Resolve<ClassB>()))` when autofac can resolve the constructor parameters without them being specified while registering. Pardon my knowledge of Autofac as i was unable to understand much of what was written in the Autofac wiki. I am looking for possible scenarios for the same. If you can provide any link or book, etc. then it would be really helpful.