# Register autofac component with optional parameters object

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I would like to register a component with an optional parameter in the constructor.
I saw [passing optional parameter to autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274547/passing-optional-parameter-to-autofac) that looks good but not sure how I can implement this with xml configuration.

Let's say this is my code:

```
public Service(IRepo repo, IEnumerable<IServiceVisitor> serviceVisitors = null)
{
    this._repo= repo;
    _serviceVisitors= serviceVisitors;
}
```

and I want to inject the complex type `IServiceVisitor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to inject `IServiceVisitor`s into `Service` you only have to register them.

```xml
<configuration>
  <autofac defaultAssembly="App">    
    <components>
      <component type="App.Service" 
                 service="App.IService"  />  
      <component type="App.ServiceVisitor1" 
                 service="App.IServiceVisitor"  />  
      <component type="App.ServiceVisitor2" 
                 service="App.IServiceVisitor"  />  
    </components>    
  </autofac>
</configuration>
```

In this case you don't need to specify the default value of `IEnumerable<IServiceVisitor>`. *Autofac* will automatically generates an empty array if no `IServiceVisitor` is registered.

```
public Service(IRepo repo, IEnumerable<IServiceVisitor> serviceVisitors)
{ /* ... */ }
```

If you don't need a `IEnumerable<IServiceVisitor>` but need an optional `IServiceVisitor` you only have to declare it as optional in the constructor using `= null`

```
public Service(IRepo repo, IServiceVisitor serviceVisitor = null)
{ /* ... */ }
```